# Unison not working after upgrade to catalina

Tags: macos-catalina, unison

Unison stopped working as soon as I upgraded to Mac OS X Catalina. When I start the pre-compiled binary (latest version 2.51.2), its window just sits there with the spinning icon indicating that it's trying to do something, but it is not prompting me for a password. nothing in the log file.

if I install Unison using macports and start that one from a terminal, same as above, except now there is an error message:

```
2020-05-03 08:42:20.947 Unison[90144:1757134] Unrecognized message from ssh:
```

That's it, no further details. I see the same problem reported already [here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/bcpierce00/unison/328/607843543). Finally, the command line/ text interface version still works well.

Would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue.  Are you using an ssh-key for access? I do, and for me doing `ssh-add -K` in a terminal window fixed the  issue (or adding the specific ssh-key works as well). See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots) for information on how to update the bash profile to avoid having to redo this (I added `ssh-add -K 2>/dev/null;` to the bash profile). There are other solutions offered in that thread, and maybe those are better  solutions.